# View extended event file

Tags: azure, extended-events

When i tried to read extended event file for azure database its giving an following error :

[image]

I am able to download .xel file from blob storage and view it through SSMS.

select * from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file ( 'http location of .xel file', null, null, null )  but its not user friendly.

Is there is any another way we can view extended event .xel file?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way that I can think of to make the interface more user-friendly and it is to create your own. I do not know if you have the time to invest into the task, but in a similar situation I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq.queryablexeventdata.aspx) library to query and parse xEvents with linq (it is the same library that Microsoft uses for the SSMS extended events viewer in SQL Server 2016).